# Don't execute setTimeout if condition changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code, that changes the class of a div when you scroll down. 
The problem is if you scroll very fast (or if I put links to a div in my menu) the timeout function doesn't execute just the last condition but all of them as a sequence. What I want to do is if the condition changes while the function is within the timeout to skip the function and check for the next condition.

```
  $(document).scroll(function() {    
  var about = jQuery('#hh1').position().top;
  var portfolio = jQuery('#hh2').position().top;
  var services = jQuery('#hh3').position().top;
  var workingprocess = jQuery('#hh4').position().top;
  var clients = jQuery('#hh5').position().top;
  var blog = jQuery('#hh6').position().top;
  var contact = jQuery('#hh7').position().top;
  var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= hh1-90 && scroll < hh3-90 || scroll >= hh5-90 && scroll < hh6-90)
  {setTimeout('$(".div").addClass("MyClass")',3440);}
  else 
  {
  setTimeout('$(".div").removeClass("MyClass")',3440);
  }
  });
```

Comment: Apart from other problems, I am scared at the fact that your scroll event handler is setting multiple timeouts and not clearing them. This will slow down you script A LOT.

You have to clear your timeout when not needed.

Comment: What are the other problems? Please tell me? I would like to fix them

Comment: For reference:  `$('.div').toggleClass('MyClass', shouldHaveClass);` will get rid of the need for the if/else.  Just take the condition you're currently using for the `if`, and assign it to a variable named `shouldHaveClass` instead.

Comment: Lobo has pointed them out. One is using an anonymous functions or an actual function instead of passing string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`setTimeout(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) method takes a function to execute when the timeout occurs. You are not sending it a function.

```
setTimeout('$(".div").addClass("MyClass")',3440);
```

Change this to

```
setTimeout(function(){$(".div").addClass("MyClass")},3440);
```

and then -

You have to store the numerical timeout id returned by the `setTimeout(...)` method and use it to clear the timeout `clearTimeout(...)`.

Save the timeout id like

```
timeoutID = setTimeout(function(){$(".div").addClass("MyClass")},3440);
```

and then use it to clear the timer.

```
clearTimeout(timeoutID);
```

You don't need to check if the timeout has occurred or not because if the timeout occurred, the function specified would have been called already and if it hasn't, you need to clear it. So, just clear the timeout when the condition changes.

Comment: Passing a string works, for compatibility reasons i imagine (the first versions of JS took a string, because they didn't support anonymous functions very well if at all), but it's hideous.

Comment: you mentioned `if the condition changes`. you should put the clear time out when the condition changes. I don't clearly understand, but i think you want it before the `if-else` and declare the `timeoutID` as global variable outside the scroll function you have shown.

Comment: Is there a way to contact you? I can't find a PM option on this website

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var addClass = function() {
    $(".div").addClass("MyClass");
}

var removeClass = function() {
    $(".div").removeClass("MyClass");
}

if (scroll >= hh1-90 && scroll < hh3-90 || scroll >= hh5-90 && scroll < hh6-90)
  {
      setTimeout( myClass,3440);
  }
  else 
  {
      setTimeout(removeClass,3440);
  }
```

Comment: Why would you redefine the `addClass` method?